# Delete parent row

Tags: mysql

Was trying to delete an "Examiner" (EX: id 2) on my schema but its not letting me do it.

Could you please help me and explain me how this constraint works on delete?
I want when I delete an examiner it sets the examinerId on exercice table as null.

```
DELETE FROM `examiner` WHERE `examiner`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1;


#1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
(`codeevaluator`.`exercise`, CONSTRAINT `FK_Exercise_ExaminerId` FOREIGN KEY         
(`examinerId`) REFERENCES `examiner` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

[image]

This is the creating schema with the two tables.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `codeevaluator`.`Examiner` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `accountId` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `accountId_UNIQUE` (`accountId` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `FQ_Examiner_AccountId`
    FOREIGN KEY (`accountId`)
   REFERENCES `codeevaluator`.`Account` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `codeevaluator`.`Exercise`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `codeevaluator`.`Exercise` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `codeevaluator`.`Exercise` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `examinerId` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED,
  `examId` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `examname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `question` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `status` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'O',
  `progress` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `nsubmissions` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `weight` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `commandbuild` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `commandrun` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `path` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT '/',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `FK_Exercise_ExamId_idx` (`examId` ASC),
  INDEX `FK_Exercise_ExaminerId_idx` (`examinerId` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Exercise_ExamId`
    FOREIGN KEY (`examId`)
    REFERENCES `codeevaluator`.`Exam` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Exercise_ExaminerId`
    FOREIGN KEY (`examinerId`)
    REFERENCES `codeevaluator`.`Examiner` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the examiner still has exercises. The constraint makes sure that there will never be an exercise which has an examiner that does not exist. Possible solutions are:

- Delete the exercises as well. This can be done manually or by changing the DB-schema to cascade deletes.
- Don't delete the examiner. Check if marking as invisible is enough. This requires to add a flag as new column and change the application(s) that access the data to respect the flag.